# why passing context as parameter in sqliteopenhelper() contructor

Tags: android, sqlite

i want to create a database and a table. in all the searches i have done first thing is to call the constructor of SQLiteOpenHelper class. i get confused with the arguments passing..can anyone please explain this concept

Comment: refer - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Comment: What part you need an explanation for, specifically?

Comment: I personally prefer working on db differently . https://bitbucket.org/kevlin/android/src/4bc1945c5e0de5d814ca1def85e8acfe4b120718/Sqlitedb/?at=master I wrote this code sometime back, you can check on sqlite implementation

Comment: i want explanation for the parameters passing

Comment: So when you read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html), what part was unclear there?

Comment: i get confused with parameters of this constructor SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)

Comment: what will contentprovider do.it is a resource means?? what is the link between contentprovider and sqliteopenhelper??